# How to load files in a specific order

Tags: activepivot

I would like to know how I can load some files in a specific order. For instance, I would like to load my files according to their timestamp, in order to make sure that subsequent data updates are replayed in the proper order.

Lets say I have 2 types of files : deal info files and risk files.

I would like to load T1_Info.csv, then T1_Risk.csv, T2_Info.csv, T2_Risk.csv...

I have tried to implement a comparator, as it is said on Confluence, but it seems that the loadInstructions file has the priority. It will order the Info files and the risk files independently. (loading T1_Info.csv, T2_Info.csv and then T1_Risk.csv, T2_Risk.csv..)

Do I have to implement a custom file loader, or is it possible using an AP configuration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loading of the files based on load instructions is done in 
`com.quartetfs.tech.store.csv.impl.CSVDataModelFactory.load(List<FileLoadDescriptor>)`. The `FileLoadDescriptor` list you receive is created directly from the load instructions files.

What you can do is create a simple instructions files with 2 entries, one for deal info and one for risk. So your custom implementation of `CSVDataModelFactory` will be called with a list of two items. In your custom implementation you scan the directory where the files are, sort them in the order you want them to be parsed and call the `super.load()` with the list of FileLoadDescriptor you created from the directory scanning.

If you want to also load files that are place in the future in this folder you have to add to your load instructions a line that will match all files and that will make the `super.load()` implementation to create a directory watcher for that (you should then maybe override `createDirectoryWatcher()` to not watch the files already present in the folder when `load` is called).